# How to make my div collapsed by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, show-hide

http://jsfiddle.net/98ftvycL/

I figured out how to make a toggle button which hides and shows the div with the content, but how can I make the content hidden by default and the toggle button to show the content

```
$(function(){
    $('a.toggle').click(function(){
        $('#content').stop().slideToggle(500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Use css #content{display: none;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/98ftvycL/1/).

The trick is to hide the entry when the page loads.

```
$(function(){
    // New code
    $("#content").hide();
    $('a.toggle').click(function(){
        $('#content').stop().slideToggle(500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

See also the jQuery docs on [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

An alternative way shown in this additional [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/98ftvycL/3/) is to set the "`display:none;`" CSS property on the div in the first place.

```
<div style="display: none;" id="content">
   <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

If you also want to hide the button when the content is shown, we can again use the `.hide()` function to now hide the button.  Another [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/98ftvycL/4/) is available. The core code for this becomes:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.toggle').click(function(){
        $('#content').stop().slideToggle(500);

        // Start of new code
        $('.toggle').hide();
        // End of new code

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, could you help me with another problem, is there anyway to do it so that when you click the toggle button, to hide the button and show the content instead of the button

I hope I'm clear: when you click the button, it should hide it and show the content instead

Comment: @common It is not clear to me what you mean "in the place of the button".  In your example, wouldn't that be the same as hiding the button?  Do you want your content moved in the DOM to where your button is?  Or maybe have the content the text of the button?

Comment: @common do you want to alternate between what is shown? So that when they click the button, the button disappears and the content is shown?

Comment: @Mr.E yes thats what I'm looking for! sorry for my English, I didn't really know how to explain this, when you click the toggle button it should hide and show the content instead of the button

Comment: @common I have updated the answer with a potential solution for your last post.

Comment: @Kolban YES! Is there anyway to make the content move a bit up?

Comment: @common As the solution stands right now, the button is 100% removed and the content has taken its place.  If you wish, you can restyle the content when the button is hidden to position it in different places by modifying the CSS style of the content.

Comment: Ah got it! Thanks a lot to you and the other guys who helped me

I hope you have a good weekend!

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS to hide content during page load.

**CSS:**

```
#content{
    display:none;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('a.toggle').click(function(){
        $('#content').stop().slideToggle(500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This would be the preffered way to using `hide()`. Always use CSS alternatives when possible.